# Separate two-way data binding in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a custom table component that expects a model for some row selection actions that can be two-way bound like so:

```
<my-table [(selected)]="selectedRows"></my-table>
```

Optionally, I can also simply pass an item via one-way data binding if I don't care about the changes that happen to that model:

```
<my-table [selected]="selectedRows"></my-table>
```

If I want to not have a two-way bound data item, and instead want to have a data item I pass down to the table component via one-way data binding, and a handler/event emitter so that the syntax ends up not to different than this:

```
<my-table [selected]="selectedRows" (selected)="handleSelectedChanged($event)"></my-table>
```

Is it possible with no, or minimal changes to the `my-table` component? Or do I have to create an `@Output` parameter on the `my-table` component to which I pass `handleSelectedChanged($event)`?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show `my-table` component code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you don't need to do any changes inside the `my-table` component table. Only when you want to use custom event to be emitted use `(selectedChange)` instead of `(selected)` that's it. I hope you already had `Input` binding `selected` and `Output` binding `selectedChange` in a place inside `my-table` component. Also selected change property binding is completely optional.

```
<my-table 
  [selected]="selectedRows" 
  (selectedChange)="handleSelectedChanged($event)">
</my-table>
```

---

If you're wondering how two way binding stuff needed to have `Change` suffix on event, because that's by design. For understanding it more clearly you can have a look at angular ngModel directive as well.

```
<input [ngModel]="myModel" (ngModelChange)="myModel = $event" />
// You can also do assignment by calling function
<input [ngModel]="myModel" (ngModelChange)="inpuChanged($event)" />
```

can be written as

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myModel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

### parent.component.html

```
<my-table [selected2]="selectedRows" (selected)="handleSelectedChanged($event)"></my-table>
```

### parent.component.ts

```
handleSelectedChanged(event){
    // console.log(event)
      this.selectedRows = event
    }
```

### my-table.component.ts

```
@Input() selected2: any;
@Output() selected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

OnCLCICK(){
 this.selected.emit({'key':'value'})
}
```

or :--

### user.service.ts

```
@Output() selected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

 setselected(data) {
 this.selected.emit(data);
}

getselected() {
        return this.selected;
      }
```

### my-table.component.ts

```
@Input() selected2: any;

constructor(
public user: Userservice
){
}

 onclick(){
this.user.setselected({'key','val'})
}
```

### parent.component.html

```
<my-table [selected2]="selectedRows"></my-table>
```

### parent.componnet.ts

```
    constructor(
    public user: Userservice
    ){
    }

ngOnInit(){
this.userService.getselected().subscribe((data) => {
      this.getData(data);
    });
}

getData(data){
console.log(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `my-table.component.ts` already has an `@Input()` and `@Output()` implemented i.e through `selected` and `selectedChange()` .

For a custom two way data binding , angular expects the event emitter and the variable to be something like this :

`@Input() date : date ;`

`@Output() dateChange : EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter<Date>();`

So when you use `[(date)]` , you have a two way data binding created .

if you don't want to use two way data binding you can omit the `()` in the `[(date)]`  and just use `[date]` , and it will still behave like a normal parent child component communication .

If you want to listen to the changes and do some action to the `date` variable value , then you can use `(dateChange)` event emitter and bind it with a function so that you can listen for the changes .

Now to answer your question whether you have to create a new `@Output()` in `my-table.component.ts` , well you don't have to create any thing or add any event emitters to bind your `handleSelectedChanged($event)` as an Event Emitter is implemented through  `selectedChange()` . All you have to do now is :

`<my-table [selected]="selectedRows" (selectedChange)='handleSelectedChanged($event)'></my-table>`

So now you have `selectedRows` as an input and `selectedChange` as an output that emits an `event` if anything changes in `selected` and the event is passed through `handleSelectedChanged()` .